# Second career as an avionics technician

Tags: avionics

I will soon be retiring from my first career as an electrician on large construction projects. Planning on becoming an active private pilot again and I am 
basically an aviation nut. I am curious as to what certifications are needed to be employable at an avionics shop ? What would be the best/quickest route to get there?

Comment: I think it may help to clarify if you want to work in an avionics backshop performing component level repairs or performing avionics line maintenance. The two are quite different and require different levels of certification. The term “avionics shop” could be confused for either in the industry.

Comment: Good points, @Frank. I assumed line maintenance because the OP said he worked as an electrician, and not a component-level repair tech.

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes you live in the United States. You should consider attending a Part 147 program at an Aviation Maintenance Technician School approved by the FAA. Some avionics technicians also get themselves an Airframe mechanic's rating from the FAA because a good percentage of what a line avionics technician does has to do with components of the airframe. (As a side note, military experience as a line avionics tech is considered sufficient to qualify to take the tests for the Airframe mechanic rating). You can also become certified through a repair station, but that may only qualify you to perform specific work. You should definitely also get the FCC radio-telephone operator certification or Aircraft Electronics Technician (AET) certification from the National Center for Aerospace and Transportation Technologies.